# Show that the set $E=\{(x,y):x^2+2y^2<6\}$ is open

Tags: general-topology, analysis

$E=\{(x,y):x^2+2y^2<6\}$

Let $X=(x,y)$

how can I find radius  $ $ $r>0$ such that $B_r(X)\subset E$ for all $X\in E$ ?

Comment: The choice of $r$ will depend on the choice of $X$.  Have you been introduced to continuous fuctions yet ?

Comment: $r< \text{distance } x$ to edge of $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $E$ is the interior of an ellipse, with standard form $\frac{x^{2}}{6} + \frac{y^{2}}{3} = 1$.

It is not hard to prove that such a ball $B_{r}(X) \subset E$ exists for every $X \in E$ just by using the definition of openness. In particular, $E$ is an open set because $f(x,y) = x^{2} + 2y^{2}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and thus $f^{-1}( (-\infty, 6) )$ is necessarily an open set. And furthermore, by definition any point in an open set necessarily has an open ball around it contained in the set.

However, if you want to explicitly compute the maximum $r$ for which $B_{r}(X) \subset E$, then that would be a more tedious problem in geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Let a point $z_0=(x_0,y_0)\in E$ be given. As $x_0^2+2y_0^2<6$ we know a priori that $|x_0|<3$ and $|y_0|<2$. The quantity $q:=6-x_0^2-2y_0^2$ measures somehow the distance from $z_0$ to the boundary of $E$; it satisfies $0<q\leq 6$. Put $$r:={q\over 18}\ .$$
I claim that $B_r(z_0)\subset E$.

*Proof.* Consider a point $(x,y)=(x_0+\Delta x,y_0+\Delta y)\in B_r(z_0)$. Then
$$x^2+2y^2=x_0^2+2y_0^2+2x_0\Delta x+4y_0\Delta y+\Delta x^2+2\Delta y^2\leq x_0^2+2y_0^2+6r +8r +3r^2\ .$$
As $3r={q\over6}\leq1$ we obtain that
$$x^2+2y^2=x_0^2+2y_0^2+15 r<x_0^2+2y_0^2+q=6\ .$$
This proves $(x,y)\in E$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove that $h_{a}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}:(x,y)\mapsto(x,ay)$ is an homeomorphism for all $a\neq 0$, that is $h$ is bijective, continuous and $h^{-1}$ is continuous.

We have, for any sequence $(x_{n},y_{n})$ converging to some $(x,y)$ that $(x_{n},ay_{n})$ converges to $(x,ay)$ with respect to the euclidean distance (well-known result).

We then have, for any sequence $(x_{n},y_{n})$ converging to $(x,y)$, that $h(x_{n},y_{n})=(x_{n},ay_{n})$ converges to $(x,ay)=h(x,y)$, so that $h$ is continuous. It is clearly bijective and by replacing $a$ by $a^{-1}$, we have that $h^{-1}$ is continuous and $h$ is an homeomorphism.

As open sets are sent by homeomorphisms onto open sets, we have that $E$ is an open set because it is nothing but the image of $B_{\sqrt{6}}(0,0)$ by $h_{(\sqrt{2})^{-1}}$:

$$h_{(\sqrt{2})^{-1}}\left(B_{\sqrt{6}}(0,0)\right)=\left\{\left(x,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y\right)\,|\,x^{2}+y^{2}<6\right\}=\left\{\left(x,y\right)\,|\,x^{2}+(\sqrt{2}y)^{2}<6\right\}=E$$